# Is it possible to host the contents of a Google Cloud Storage Bucket as a 'subfolder' in the url hierarchy of an App Engine Nodejs/Expressjs app?

Tags: node.js, express, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Essentially, I would like map the url `customdomain.com/gcdownload/*` to a gc storage bucket so that the download actually comes from the `customdomain.com` site, rather than from `storage.googleapis.com/%bucketname%`.
Eg. mapping `customdomain.com/gcdownload/a/b/c.pdf` to `%bucketname%/a/b/c.pdf` while still serving `c.pdf` from `customdomain.com`.

I did successfully rewrite the download request urls to the storage bucket urls but then the downloads are cross-site requests to the `storage.googleapis.com` domain so doesn't achieve the goal.

Any way to configure the storage bucket/app engine domain/app code to support serving the static files of a storage bucket as a 'subfolder' of a custom domain?

Comment: Because storage bucket doesn't exist, I would like to say no!

Comment: What you did is the only way.  You could cache the storage URLs to make it faster.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this if you put a Google Cloud Load Balancer in front of your GAE.

You would first have to setup a GCLB with a serverless NEG for your app engine services:

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs#serverless-neg

You would then add a backend bucket to your GCS bucket:

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/ext-load-balancer-backend-buckets

You would then setup the URL map of the GCLB to route `/gcdownload/*` to your backend bucket and all other traffic to your app engine.